# sitemap, javascript redirection and google

Tags: javascript, redirect, sitemap

I have a site, which show all products in a grid on its index page. I use a hash symbol to make some of the products active (I mean - some products are shown with a border around it, others are inactive). Ex: `http://mysite.net/#15` --> shows product #15 with a border, all other are inactive.

Unfortunately, that format is not so good for indexing in Google, because all products and info are in one place and I can't form a good structure for that. To solve that, I wrote a script that generates a single product view with another URL. Ex: `http://mysite.com/product/color_separation.html` --> shows only one product. This is good to use in the sitemap, But I want my visitors to see the products in a grid view.

If I put some javascript in a single page view to redirect visitors from `http://mysite.com/product/color_separation.html` to the grid view with the product activated at `http://mysite.net/#15` will this cause any trouble when the Google bot is going through all single pages in the sitemap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Bot will have no trouble visiting the single view page but using Javacript for redirect the user to another page will probably be seen as cloaking, more information in [Google Webmaster Tools support](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2721217&topic=2371375&ctx=topic)

I tought you can use the HTML5 History API but as all your products are in the same page (and URL) and the change is only cosmetic that will not help you. Google may just seen [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359).

If you want all the products indexed in Google, you have to make one unique URL for each of them.
It's the meaning of the **R** (Ressource) in *URL* :).